# SQL Server : check not existing number into a table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a `Clients` table already populated by thousands of records and now I need to search for a non-existing number in the `card number` column starting from the number `x`.

Example: I would like to search for the first available `card number` starting from number 2000.

Unfortunately I cannot select `MAX()` as there are records with 9999999 (which is the limit).

Is it possible to do this search through a single `SELECT`?

Comment: Could you please give some sample data and mention what you've tried so far interms of coding?

Comment: `code`[dbo].[Clients]
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Surname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [CardCode] [int] NULL
`code`
the table already contains thousands of records and up to now the "CardCode" field was user insertable. CardCode must be unique.
Now I need a query that gives me the first "CardCode" available since issue 2000. Mine was a feasibility request. Is it possible to do this with a query? If so, how?

Comment: Storing all available card numbers in a separate table and marking them if they are used or not might be a good start to keep track of unused numbers for it. There are ways to identify it in a single select but it might raise some performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

If the credit card is represented as integer in your table and your starting number is `2000` you could do something like:

```
SELECT top 1 (card_id + 1) 
FROM CreditCards t
WHERE card_id IN (
    SELECT card_id
    FROM CreditCards
    WHERE card_id LIKE '%[2][0][0][0]%'
)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CreditCards t2 WHERE t2.card_id = t.card_id + 1)
ORDER BY card_id
```

Example data (Table: CreditCards):

| card_id |
| --- |
| 2000002 |
| 2000103 |
| 2000000 |
| 2000108 |
| 2000106 |
| 3000201 |
| 1000101 |

Result is: 2000001

Note that `%[2][0][0][0]%` is fixed here. You could also introduce a parameter.

It is not an optimal solution, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a few nested `SELECT`s:

```
SELECT MIN(`card_number`) + 1 as next_available_number
  FROM( SELECT (2000-1) as `card_number`
        UNION
        SELECT `card_number`
        FROM clients
        WHERE `card_number` >= 2000
      ) tmp
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM clients
                   WHERE `card_number` = tmp.`card_number` + 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a self-join on your `clients` table, where you search for the lowest `cardnumber` for which the `cardnumber + 1` does not exist.

In case `x` is `12`, the query would be:

```
SELECT MIN(cardnumber) + 1
FROM clients
WHERE cardnumber + 1 NOT IN (SELECT cardnumber FROM clients)
  AND cardnumber + 1 > 12
```

Eg. with a dataset of

```
INSERT INTO clients (cardnumber) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(17),(18)
```

this returns 16, but not 10.
Example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b8996f/1).

I think this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587799/returning-the-lowest-integer-not-in-a-list-in-sql), but the minimum criteria is new.